# CloudWatch Amazon Aws - Create Alarm in LB to monitorize if Apache Solr is down?

Tags: solr, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want create a alert alarm in my Load Balancer to monitorize if Apache Solr is down in my server, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [PingRequestHandler](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/PingRequestHandler.html) of Solr to keep a watch on the Health of your Solr instance.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7251388/326543) talks about how to use a HealthCheck file to return back the status of your instance.

Comment: Another question: You know if is it possible check Solr health with the Route53 Service??'

Comment: I must confess I've never used Route53, but it looks like you could point a Route53 health-check to Solr Ping. Ref [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-creating-deleting.html)